# PHP Registration Form not saving

Tags: php, mysql

I have  a HTML Sign Up form that allows new users to be registered to the site.:

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST" class="register-form">
    <h1>Create Account</h1>
    <label>
        <span>First Name :</span>
        <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name" autocomplete="off" required/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Surname :</span>
        <input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Your Surname" autocomplete="off" required/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Username :</span>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Chosen Username" autocomplete="off" required/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Email :</span>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" autocomplete="off" required/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Password :</span>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Chosen Password" autocomplete="off" required/>
    </label>
    <hr>
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="signup" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn register btn-success btn-lg" name="submit" value="Register">

</form>
```

Which goes to register.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

$select_db = mysql_select_db('gmaps1');
if (!$select_db) {
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (firstname, surname, username, password, email) VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$username', '$password', '$email')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result) {
        header("Location: thank_you.html");
    } else {
        echo 'User Not Created';
    }
}
?>
```

But when I click the Register button it doesn't save the data and returns  "User Not Created". Would it be better using MySQLi rather than MySQL or is there a better way for this to work??

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. That will tell you if there are any issues.

Comment: check log file, share the error if there is anything

Comment: Btw, you do plan on storing a hashed password, right? This isn't intended for a live site I hope.

Comment: I would *guess* that at least one of the fields contains a `'` character.  Since you're neither escaping your user-provided strings nor passing them to MySQL out-of-band (as parameters to prepared statements), quotation characters *will result in buggy behaviour* that can be abused to perform SQL injection attacks!   See http://bobby-tables.com/ for more info.

Comment: For now passwords hashed passwords are not a priority as it is for a college project and will just be running on my localserver

Answer (score 1):

Error checking solved my problem - "field 'active' doesn't have a default value"

There was an inactive field in the table 'Users'. I got rid of that and it works fine. It must have been added in by mistake.

Comment: Oh yes, it was error checking, I amended my answer to reflect this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't get a "Database Connection Failed" so you sucessfully connected with the database
- Its better to use MySQLi or PDO (my choice)
- At least use [`mysql_real_escape`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and maybe a `trim()` but thats just a starting point when it comes to security
- check wether all your database fields are named exactly the way you are adressing them inside your Insert-Statement
- Do a `echo $query`, open phpMyAdmin (for example) and copy-paste the output inside the SQL field and send -> you may get a MySQL error you can analyse
- It's better to store passwords hashed. Try inserting `MD5($password)` (there are way better options!) and on login do compare:

  if(MD5($inputPassword) == $passwordhashFromDatabase){}